# How do you launch a model UITableViewController from a UITableViewCell with a delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

So, I am pretty sure I am very close to getting this to work. I think it is maybe only the `.delegate =` line that doesn't work.

Firstly the protocol

```
protocol beever1: class {
    func beever2()
}
```

Now in the **UITableViewCell1**:

```
var delegate1: beever1?
```

On long press, the below code runs in a funciton (I can't return via UIContextMenuConfiguration because there is a database check in UIContextMenuConfiguration - that's why I am presenting instead of returning).

```
if let delegate3 = self.delegate1{ 
delegate3.beever2()
}
```

Then in the **UITableViewController1** that needs to be launched on the longpress

```
extension UITableViewController1: beever1 {
func beever2() {
    
    let image3 = UIImage(named:"green.png")
    if let unwrappedImage1 = image3 {
        self.present(ImagePreviewController(image:unwrappedImage1), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
}
// I know this part works because I could successfull ypresent it on another VC


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell1 {
    
    **cell.delegate1 = self**.
    
    // probably where error is but I think it makes sense as is: I am sending delegate info from cell to this UITableViewContoller bacause I want the UITableViewContoller to launch, right?///
    return cell
}
return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Update:

I now think I understand why it isn't presenting, but am not sure how to fix it. UITableViewController1 is not loaded on screen when the long press is made. UITableViewCell1 on a 3rd TableViewController is loaded on screen. Then on long press UITableViewController1 needs to appear. So because UITableViewController1 is not loaded and only needs to be loaded on long press, the cellForRowAt function isn't automatically read

What I think I could do, but am not sure how to code. Option1) on the UITableViewCell1 I need to somehow code the delegate to be self.delegate1 = UITableViewController1, but currently that doesn't work

The Option 2 is the 3rd TableViewController on which the UITableViewCell1 is located. In it's cellForRowAt I could say: cell.delegate1 = UITableViewController1. But that also currently doesn't work

Do y'all agree with my assessment?

Comment: cell.delegate1 = self , is correct, use this line in cellForRowAt method. self is your ViewController instance, only one instance can be assign to delegate variable. If you are using **blabla.delegate = self** with different places, it will overridden by latest assignment.

Comment: replace it **delegate1?.beever2()**  with following lines: 

if let delegate3 = self.delegate1{ 
delegate3.beever2()
}

Comment: and replace **var delegate1: beever1?** with following **weak var delegate1: beever1?**

Comment: Thanks. I tried those but it didn't work. I think I understand why, but am not sure how to fix. UITableViewController1 is not loaded on screen when the long press is made. UITableViewCell1 on a 3rd TableViewController is loaded on screen. Then on long press UITableViewController1 needs to appear. So because UITableViewController1 is not loaded and only needs to be loaded on long press, the cellForRowAt function isn't automatically read.

Comment: What I think I could do, but am not sure how to code. Option1) on the UITableViewCell1 I need to somehow code the delegate to be self.delegate1 = self, but currently that doesn't work cause it says cannot assign value of type 'ViewControllerTableViewCell' to type 'beever1?'

Comment: The Option 2 is the 3rd TableViewController on which the UITableViewCell1 is located. In it's cellForRowAt I could say: cell.delegate1 = UITableViewCell1. But that currently doesn't work because it also says Cannot assign value of type 'ViewControllerTableViewCell' to type 'beever1?'

Comment: Do you agree with my assessment?